# Updating an element from a button click

Tags: reactjs

pretty new to react and was trying to figure out the best way to handle updating a custom widget from a button click. I have 3 widgets so far - a text box, button, and a twitter embedded feed. I want to basically update the twitter feed to re-render with the input in the text box after the button is clicked:

```
constructor(props){
      super(props)
      console.debug(props)
      this.state = {
        searchTerm: "test",
        selectedOption: null
      }
      this.onTextChange = this.onTextChange.bind(this);
      this.appChange = this.appChange.bind(this);
      this.searchClicked = this.searchClicked.bind(this);
    }

    onTextChange(e){
      this.setState({
        searchTerm: e.target.value
      });
    };

    appChange = selectedOption => {
      this.setState({ selectedOption });
      console.log('Option: ', selectedOption);
    }

    searchClicked(e){
      this.setState({
        searchTerm: e.target.value
      })

render() {
        const { searchTerm } = this.state;


        return(
          <div>
            <div className="hashtag">
                <input name="search" type="text" className="textBox" placeholder={this.state.searchTerm} onInput={this.onTextChange}/>
                <br />
                <button id="btnSearch" className="searchBtn" onClick={this.searchClicked}>Search</button>
                <TwitterTimelineEmbed
                  sourceType="profile"
                  screenName={this.state.searchTerm}
                  options={{height:400, width: 400}}
                />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I've tried using componentDidUpate(), but haven't been successful for passing in previous props/state.

Comment: What is happening now? Is it updating immediately when the input changes?

Comment: No the twitter feed isn't updating at all, it just renders as the default search term value

Comment: If you are destructuring your state in render() you no longer need to pass `this.state.searchTerm` in your code, you can simply use `searchTerm`.  In your render() simply do a `console.log(searchTerm)` to make sure your render() is working as expected.

Comment: the button is outputting the searchTerm correctly (after updating via textBox)- but the twitter feed is re-rendering with the new output.

Comment: What is `TwitterTimelineEmbed`? If that component doesn't respond correctly to updates to the `screenName` prop then you will need a different solution.

Comment: It is a custom react component I found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-twitter-embed -- I'm also looking into adding an event listener for the button click on the Twitter widget

Comment: Take a look at my code snippet in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56706558/319010

Comment: The solution is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you click submit you are overriding the state with `e.target.value` - which is nothing since the `e.target` is the actual submit button, not the input field.

You don't need to `setState` inside of `searchClicked` since the state is updated on each keypress (in `onTextChange`).

I also removed `appChange` since you don't need it in this code snippet.

**The solution** requires for you to add a `key` to the `<TwitterTimelineEmbed />` so that the old instance gets destroyed whenever you want to update the username.

It is good that the Twitter component doesn't allow you to update the component on a state change as otherwise you could easily accidentally call the Twitter API on every re-render which may (most likely) not what you want.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import { TwitterTimelineEmbed } from "react-twitter-embed";

class Search extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.timelineId = 0; // initialize key

    this.state = {
      searchTerm: "TwitterEng"
    };

    this.onTextChange = this.onTextChange.bind(this);
    this.searchClicked = this.searchClicked.bind(this);
  }

  onTextChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      searchTerm: e.target.value
    });
  }

  searchClicked(e) {
    // notice we removed the setState

    ++this.timelineId; // this is the key for the timelinefeed

    this.forceUpdate(); // you need to force update here if you want to update on search
  }

  render() {
    const { searchTerm } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="hashtag">
          <input
            name="search"
            type="text"
            className="textBox"
            placeholder={searchTerm}
            onInput={this.onTextChange}
          />
          <br />
          <button
            id="btnSearch"
            className="searchBtn"
            onClick={this.searchClicked}
          >
            Search
          </button>
          <TwitterTimelineEmbed
            key={this.timelineId}
            sourceType="profile"
            screenName={searchTerm}
            options={{ height: 400, width: 400 }}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: thanks! I've tried this as well and the Twitter widget doesn't update when the searchTerm state is updated (stays static with the initial searchTerm)

Comment: @nobrac I have updated the code snippet that does what you want it to do.  Basically you need to add a `key` to the Twitter component to ensure it properly gets destroyed and re-created on every re-render.  I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks! out of curiosity how did you determine that `key` was a usable attribute for `TwitterTimelineEmbed` ?

Comment: `key` is a React attribute that is available to all components.

Answer (score 0):

So I did a couple things which should fix your problem. You were pretty close!

```
<input name="search" type="text" className="textBox" value={this.state.searchTerm} onChange={this.onTextChange}/>
```

First, I changed `placeholder` to `value` on your input.  This will make it so that the input field is properly updated when the user types.  I also changed `onInput` to `onChange` on this field.  This will make it so that the update function actually fires.

```
twitterOutput: ""
```

Next, I added a new state value for the twitter window.  If you only want this to update when the user clicks a button, you will have to store this in a separate variable.  Otherwise when the user types, it will automatically be tied to the twitter window as well.  If that is the behavior you wanted, you can stop here!

```
searchClicked(e){
  this.setState({
    twitterOutput: this.state.searchTerm
  })
}

<TwitterTimelineEmbed
  sourceType="profile"
  screenName={this.state.twitterOutput}
  options={{height:400, width: 400}}
/>
```

Finally, I changed the click function to update your new `twitterOutput` state value so that it will update your timeline, as well as changed the prop on the Twitter element to reflect that.

Let me know if this helps!

Full Code:

```js
constructor(props){
      super(props)
      console.debug(props)
      this.state = {
        searchTerm: "test",
        selectedOption: null,
        twitterOutput: ""
      }
      this.onTextChange = this.onTextChange.bind(this);
      this.appChange = this.appChange.bind(this);
      this.searchClicked = this.searchClicked.bind(this);
    }

    onTextChange(e){
      this.setState({
        searchTerm: e.target.value
      });
    };

    appChange = selectedOption => {
      this.setState({ selectedOption });
      console.log('Option: ', selectedOption);
    }

    searchClicked(e){
      this.setState({
        twitterOutput: this.state.searchTerm
      })
    }

render() {
        const { searchTerm } = this.state;


        return(
          <div>
            <div className="hashtag">
                <input name="search" type="text" className="textBox" value={this.state.searchTerm} onChange={this.onTextChange}/>
                <br />
                <button id="btnSearch" className="searchBtn" onClick={this.searchClicked}>Search</button>
                <TwitterTimelineEmbed
                  sourceType="profile"
                  screenName={this.state.twitterOutput}
                  options={{height:400, width: 400}}
                />
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [React hooks](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiF3ej5jPviAhVS-qwKHQfhBGkQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Freactjs.org%2Fdocs%2Fhooks-intro.html&usg=AOvVaw3y1NC1kywtUyC-dvthI7T5)? Here's a codepen with React 16.8.6 that solves your problem.

```
import React, { useState} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const App = () => {
  const [screenName, setScreenName] = useState('');
  const [goSearch, setGoSearch] = useState(false);

  const onChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    if(goSearch) setGoSearch(false);
    setScreenName(value);
  }

  const search = () => setGoSearch(true);

  return (
    <div className='hashtag'>
      <input 
        name='search' 
        type='text'
        className='textBox' 
        placeholder='Enter a twitter screen name' 
        onChange={onChange}
        value={screenName}
      />
      <br />
      <button 
        id='btnSearch'
        className='searchBtn ' 
        onClick={search}
      >
        Search
      </button>

      {/* This section is just for example */}
      {!!screenName && goSearch &&
        <p>You searched for <b>{screenName}</b></p>
      }

      {/* Uncomment this section to use with TwitterTimelineEmbed */}
      {/*goSearch && <TwitterTimelineEmbed
          sourceType="profile"
          screenName={screenName}
          options={{height:400, width: 400}}
        />*/}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

https://codepen.io/bflemi3/pen/mZWwYw

There's more than one way to accomplish this. I chose to keep the search term and when to actually perform the search separate. Once the user clicks `Search` the `TwittterTimelineEmbed` is rendered with the updated screenName given as the prop.